# Angelscript transfer array from C++

Tags: c++, angelscript

I need to transfer an array of tiles from C++ to Angelscript, I have tried adding a function that returns an std::vector but it returns this error

```
Failed in call to function 'RegisterGlobalFunction' with 'array<DumbTile> GetTilesAt(int x, int y)' (Code: asINVALID_DECLARATION, -10)
```

my code:

```
std::vector<DumbTile> GetTilesAt(int x, int y) {
    std::vector<DumbTile> output;
    for (DumbTile t : tiles) {
        if (t.x == x && t.y == y) {
            output.push_back(t);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
engine->RegisterGlobalFunction("array<DumbTile> GetTilesAt(int x, int y)", asFUNCTIONPR(GetTilesAt, (int, int), std::vector<DumbTile>), asCALL_CDECL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `DumbTile` registered before `GetTilesAt()` registration?

Is `array<T>` registered before `GetTilesAt()` registration?

Both needs to be registered before you can register your function.

Are you using stock array implementation (`sdk/add_on/scriptarray/`) or your own, `std::vector<>`-based implementation? When using stock addon, application must convert `std::vector` to `CScriptArray` first, as angelscript can't really do that on its own due to way how arrays works.

There is obvious alternative - switch from using `std::vector` to `CScriptArray` everywhere where you want scripts to access data, but this might be annoying.

---

Example `std::vector<Object*> <-> CScriptArray*` conversion

```cpp
template<typename Type>
void AppendVectorToArrayRef( vector<Type>& vec, CScriptArray* arr )
{
    if( !vec.empty() && arr )
    {
        uint i = (uint)arr->GetSize();
        arr->Resize( (asUINT)(i + (uint)vec.size() ) );
        for( uint k = 0, l = (uint)vec.size(); k < l; k++, i++ )
        {
            Type* p = (Type*)arr->At( i );
            *p = vec[k];
            (*p)->AddRef();
        }
    }
}
```

```cpp
template<typename Type>
void AssignScriptArrayInVector( vector<Type>& vec, CScriptArray* arr )
{
    if( arr )
    {
        uint count = (uint)arr->GetSize();
        if( count )
        {
            vec.resize( count );
            for( uint i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            {
                Type* p = (Type*)arr->At( i );
                vec[i] = *p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code is bit old but i think it should still work, even if it begs for some refresh.

Comment: I'm using the stock array implementation, how can I convert an std::vector to a CScriptArray?

Comment: @BBQGiraffe Updated answer, sorry for delay.